# Convert vm to native/dual-boot

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

Long shot:  I run an ubuntu 10.4 machine under VMware, Windows 7 host.  I use it more and more as my primary machine, and wish now that I had installed it as a dual boot system, since the sluggishness of the vm is a continual irritation.  So -- is it possible somehow to convert the ubuntu system to run natively?

If not, are there any tools to help me transfer all my files and settings to a new dual-boot Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 1):

Well.... you can use qemu-img to extract the raw image of the filesystem.

I would do this:

```
1) Booting a live cd with qemu-img tool
2) Dump vmware image into a external usb hard-drive in raw format.
3) Shrink NTFS partition to make room for the ubuntu
        image and swap (or more, if you want)
4) Create a new ext3 partition and swap partition to fill in the new free space
5) Dump the raw image to the new ext3
6) [resizefs if partition > size(raw image)]
7) chroot to the new ext3 partition
8) execute grub-install to (hd0)
9) test if works
```

I made a similar thing before and it worked

Comment: Great, thanks for that Kiko!  So I guess surgery is required after all.

Comment: Another idea is recreating your system. That way, you'll do some cleaning :D.

1) Booting vm ubuntu. dpkg --get-selections > your_packages_list.txt
2) copy that file to a pen drive
2.b) copy /home, /var/www, ... to the pen drive (use tar cvfj to preserve permission and users)
3) Shrink NTFS partition
4) create a new ext3fs and swap partition
5) install new ubuntu there
6) dpkg --set-selections < your_packages_list.txt
7) apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
8) copy /home, /var/www, ... to the new ubuntu

Comment: This is an application in Debian (and I presume Ubuntu also) that does just this, automatically. I don't seem to remember the name.